# Should I use element.myclass or .myclass in css?

Tags: css

I couldn't find explanation if I should use e.g. `element.myclass` or `.myclass` in CSS in order to style my elements.

**So, should I use**

```
[p/span/div/h1/etc..].intro {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

**or**

```
.intro {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

**?**

I know the difference between these two, but I don't know which one I need to use.

Comment: Depends on your layout and needs. Syntactically they're both fine (although the `=` is wrong -- should be `:`)

Comment: Why is this opinion based? There are 2 ways to do the same thing. I try to understand when to use element.intro or .intro

Comment: Why was this voted down? What is wrong with you people? Didn't you ever have basic questions when you were learning? There is nothing wrong with this question. Geeze.

Comment: I usually just use `.intro` unless I need to target a specific child element, which is the other method.

Comment: You need to use the one you need to use .... there is no wrong way here it's all about specificity

Comment: just remember css is processed right to left so the longer your selector, the more inefficient it is going to be.  If you do not need that level of specificity, then go with the simplest selector.  Have a read of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue this is a specificity question. And as such I would go with `.intro` before `p|span|div.intro`. Selectors with higher specificity win out.

`.intro` has a specificity of `0 0 0 1`.

`p.intro` has a specificity of `0 0 1 1`, which is higher than `.intro`.

Let's say `.intro` is:

```
.intro {
    color: green;
}
```

So any element with `.intro` will have green text. But you want all paragraphs to have orange text. You can create a new class like `.p-intro` or you can do:

```
p.intro {
    color: orange;
}
```

Which does increase specificity slightly over `.p-intro` but the one *"big"* benefit is that you don't have to go through all the markup to add/remove `.p-intro` to all paragraphs. By adding `p` to `.intro` in your CSS you have updated a whole site in one stroke.

I always try to use CSS selectors with the lowest specificity to get the job done. That way, later on, it's easier to update/extend the existing styles when the inevitable changes come about.

**Note:** See other answers for other benefits.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great explanation! Both Xenos and you deserve the green checkmark :S :)

Answer (score 4):

Favor `.myclass` over `p.myclass` if the selector is not ambiguous (see hungerstar answer), as SonarQube states:

> ### Name of overqualified element should be removed
>
> Writing selectors such as li.active are unnecessary unless the element name causes the class to behave differently. In most cases, it's safe to remove the element name from the selector, both reducing the size of the CSS as well as improving the selector performance (doesn't have to match the element anymore).
>
> Removing the element name also loosens the coupling between your CSS and your HTML, allowing you to change the element on which the class is used without also needing to update the CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great explanation! Both hungerstar and you deserve the green checkmark :S :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ockham's razor, *use always the simplest approach*: If `.intro` is enough for your need, stick to it as a first option. After that, if you need to differenciate rules between several cases, enlarge the selector to make it more specific (the browser will chose *the most specific selector* in case of conflict).